# How to bind this XML to gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

How to bind below XML to Gridview?

```
<Students>
  <sem id="1">
    <student id="101">
      <mark total="700"/>
    </student>
  </sem>
  <sem id="2">
    <student id="101">
      <mark total="800"/>
    </student>
  </sem>
  <sem id="1">
    <student id="102">
      <mark total="700"/>
    </student>
  </sem>
  <sem id="2">
    <student id="102">
      <mark total="900"/>
    </student>
  </sem>
</Students>
```

I want to display grid as below

```
student   sem1  sem2
  101     700   600
  102     800   900
```

I've tried to read xml into dataset and assigned dataset table to grid source.

Answer (score 2):

Directly reading the xml file into a dataset may not give you the desired table view.
Instead you can use System.Xml namespace and its classes like XmlDocument,XmlElement etc to read the xml and create a datatable and then bind the datasource

Answer (score 0):

Use the XmlDataSource control an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479341.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may use some of the controls from the toolbox :

- Add the xml file in your project.
- Add a XMLDataSource in the aspx page.
- Configure it to refer to the xml file that was added
- Add the GridView to the aspx page
- Configure the GridView datasource to refer to the xml data source
- Then design the GridView to display the fields as per choice.